# Como funciona o banco de dados Oracle Express Edition?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Gostaria de uma explicação quanto ao funcionamento do banco de dados Express Edition disponibilizado pela Oracle para estudantes, pois pelo terminal criei uma tabela e fiz uma inserção e tudo bem , fechei o aplicativo, quando abri e fiz uma consulta os dados não estavam mais guardados e o banco informava que não havia nada na tabela em questão.
Eis duas questões:
O seu armazenamento é volátil , sendo usado só para que se possa aprender os seus comandos?
Queria uma explicação sobre o seu uso, e ele possui também uma interface gráfica?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Oracle Express Edition é idêntico às edições enterprise, tendo apenas limitações de licença e de capacidade (tamanho da base, número de usuários, performance em concorrência, etc.).

O problema que você está enfrentando se dá porque o comportamento padrão do Oracle é **iniciar implicitamente uma transação** ao receber um comando de manipulação de dados (*insert*, *delete*, *update*).

Esta transação iniciada implicitamente **precisa ser explicitamente encerrada** (com um comando *commit* ou *rolback*), do contrário o Oracle fará automaticamente o *rollback* ao final da sessão (quando você desconectar).

**Este comportamento não é o padrão de todos os SGBDs**. O Microsoft SQL Server, por exemplo, inicia e commita implicitamente uma transação a cada comando de manipulação de dados, desde que o usuário não tenha iniciado explicitamente a transação (se o usuário inciar a transação explicitamente ele também precisa fazer o commit explicitamente).

Portanto, para resolver o seu problema, depois de inserir um registro execute o comando *commit*, assim a transação será efetivada e o registro estará disponível para outros usuários (outras conexões).

Este comportamento padrão também pode ser alterado por configuração de servidor ou de sessão, mas geralmente não é uma boa idéia.

Já a interface gráfica é uma ferramenta à parte do servidor de banco de dados e existem várias disponíveis, como *Oracle SQL Developer* e *SQuirreL SQL Client*.

Answer (score 2):

Tente rodar seu comando (criação de tabela, insert, etc) e adicione ao final:

`COMMIT;`

Feche o programa e abra-o novamente e verifique se os dados continuam persistidos, caso a resposta for sim você tem que ativar o commit implícito no seu banco.

Sobre a sua pergunta sobre a versão Express, a resposta é **não**, esse banco funciona igual a versão paga quanto ao armazenamento de dados.

Answer (score 2):

**Entendendo o comportamento de um COMMIT**

Uma transação qualquer normalmente é iniciada por uma aplicação ou usuário. Durante a execução de uma transação, são geradas alterações de dados e consequentemente alterações em buffer (memória). Esta área de memória é definida através do parâmetro log_buffer. Quando um usuário ou aplicação executa um COMMIT, o Oracle imediatamente grava os dados armazenados em buffer (memória) para disco (redo log files) juntamente com os dados de redo para o commit. Enquanto este processo não for completamente concluído, (todos os dados estejam gravados nos Online Redo Log Files) o Oracle não irá “liberar” a sessão.

**Alterando o comportamento de um COMMIT**

Pode-se alterar o comportamento de uma instrucão COMMIT de 2 Formas:

1. Opções através do próprio comando COMMIT
2. Alterando a sessão ou o Ambiente

Informações retirada do link: http://imasters.com.br/artigo/24548/oracle/alterando-comportamento-de-transacoes-no-oracle-database-com-asynchronous-commit/